# BLAST Database allocation error

Tags: python, memory, mapping, allocation, blast

I asked this question on the bioinformatics version of stackexchange, but since I think it is a computer problem I thought I should try my luck here.

When running local BLAST (v2.2.24+) on a big database (all human proteins) I get the following error:

```
proteinsApplicationError: Command 'blast-2.2.24+/bin/blastp.exe -query "query.fasta" -
db "human-proteins.fasta" -out blastOutput.xml -evalue 0.01 -outfmt 5'       
returned     non-zero exit status 2, 'BLAST Database error: CSeqDBAtlas::MapMmap: 
While mapping file [human-proteins.fasta.psq] with 5550749 bytes allocated, caught 
exception:'
```

When googling I only got to the source code of seqdbatlas: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/IEB/ToolBox/CPP_DOC/lxr/source/src/objtools/blast/seqdb_reader/seqdbatlas.cpp in which I found:

```
1214         if (expt.length()) {
1215             // For now, if I can't memory map the file, I'll revert to
1216             // the old way: malloc a chunk of core and copy the data
1217             // into it.
1218             
1219             if (expt.find(": Cannot allocate memory") == expt.npos) {
1220                 expt = string("CSeqDBAtlas::MapMmap: While mapping file [") + 
                 (*m_Fname) + "] with " +
1221                     NStr::UInt8ToString(atlas->GetCurrentAllocationTotal()) +
1222                     " bytes allocated, caught exception:" + expt;
1223                 
1224                 SeqDB_ThrowException(CSeqDBException::eFileErr, expt);
1225             }
1226         }
```

My knowledge of C++ is limited, but what I get from this is that there isn't enough memory on the PC to run BLAST over that size of a database. Is this correct and if so, is there a way to run this BLAST without getting a computer with a bigger memory? If it's not correct, what is the error that I'm getting?

Thanks in advance, Niek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by breaking the query file up in two and using blast 2.2.25 instead of 2.2.24